# How do you even out list boxes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have been creating a simple program where if you select an even number of players from a checked list box they would be randomly put into two separate list boxes. It does the job but I can't seem to make the list boxes even in items. Here's the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            Random r = new Random();
            int br = listBox1.Items.Count;
            int br1 = f2.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count / 2;
            

                    foreach (string ig in Form2.igraci)
                    {
                        int x = r.Next(1, 3);
                        if (x==1 && br<=br1)
                        {

                            listBox1.Items.Add(ig);

                        }
                        else listBox2.Items.Add(ig);

                    }
         }
```

The code above always puts all the items in the second listbox and I can not seem to understand why. Thanks to anyone who takes their time to look into this little problem of mine.

Comment: I know it seems like you want to "put each player in a random list box", but what you actually want to do is line up all the items in a shuffled order, then do the schoolyard team-assigning trick of going down the shuffled list saying "you're a 1, you're a 2, you're a 1, you're a 2...etc."

Comment: `Form2 f2 = new Form2();` => `f2.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count` then `foreach (string ig in Form2.igraci)`. Maybe you found, somewhere, that setting the access modifier of Controls to public is a good idea. It's not. Plus, you're dealing with quite different instances (or non-instances) of the same Form. C# doesn't work like VB.Net in relation to Forms instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of index values, shuffle them, and then add the random list into two separate lists based on the even-odd parity of the index value:

```
String[] players = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
int[] index = new int[players.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
    index[i] = i;
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++) {
    int j = r.Next(i, index.Length);
    int x = index[i];
    index[i] = index[j];
    index[j] = x;
}
List<String> list1 = new List<String>();
List<String> list2 = new List<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        list1.Add(players[index[i]]);
    else
        list2.Add(players[index[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that `(br <= br1)` is never true so you end up adding only to listBox2